# Where to start when creating a magento new theme

Tags: magento-1.9

am a beginner in magento, I need to know where to start when creating a new theme and applying in magento.

Comment: This might help you out, http://www.magenmarket.com/news-and-blog/how-to-create-a-custom-theme-in-magento.html

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Knowledge-base of Magento RWD Developer Guide:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide